# CXF create web service client from wsdl programmatically

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I've downloaded the cxf package and linked it with eclipse. Everything works fine. I can generate the code of a web service clent from the provided wsdl. What I want now is to be able to do it programmatically. The scenario is the user can give a wsdl and then the programm takes it and creates a jar representing the client. First things first though, what I want for now is to generate the java code of the wsdl programmatically. Can this be done? And if yes do you have any tips? I don't want code or anything, just something to get started because my research has not been very productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [maven plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) to generate Java classes from a wsdl.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I haven't used maven plugins before. I'll research about that and come back with questions.

Comment: I want to invoke the wsdl2java mechanism programmatically. Are maven plugins meant to be used that way?

Comment: Your workflow is unknown to me, but you could use some scripting language to invoke java or command line actions to automate this process.